# Datos de dos tablas en la misma consulta

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Necesito mostrar los registros coincidentes de dos tablas, ordenados por fecha.
Logro mostrarlos del modo que muestro en mi código, pero por supuesto, primero muestra los datos de una tabla y luego de la otra.
Creo que lo necesario es unir las dos consultas, pero no logro hacerlo.
Agradeceré alguna sugerencia.
Saludos!

```html
$queryFC = "SELECT COM.id_facturadeventa, COM.id_cliente, COM.FacturadorTalonario, COM.TipoDeComprobante, COM.FacturaLetra, COM.facturaNumero, COM.FechaDeFactura, COM.total,COM.total, COM.Anulada, COM.Estado
FROM comprobantes COM
WHERE COM.id_cliente = '$cliente'
ORDER BY COM.FechaDeFactura DESC";


$query = "SELECT VAL.id_valrecibido, VAL.id_recibo, VAL.id_facturadeventa, VAL.id_notadecredito, VAL.tipovalor, VAL.numerovalor, VAL.banco, VAL.provinciaIIBB, VAL.cuentabancaria, VAL.caja, VAL.numretencion, VAL.bancoprovincia, VAL.bancoprovinciaValor, VAL.vencimiento, VAL.importe, VAL.ActivoNoActivo, REC.id_cliente, REC.fechaCobro, REC.fechaImputacion, REC.recibo_numero, CLI.razonsocial
FROM cobranzas_valrecibidos VAL 
LEFT JOIN cobranzas_recibos REC ON VAL.id_recibo = REC.id_recibo
LEFT JOIN clientes CLI ON CLI.id_cliente = REC.id_cliente
WHERE REC.id_cliente = '$cliente'
ORDER BY REC.fechaCobro DESC";



if(!($resultadoFC = $mysqli->query($queryFC))) {
    echo "Error al ejecutar la sentencia <b>$queryFC</b>: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
    exit;
}

if(!($resultado = $mysqli->query($query))) {
    echo "Error al ejecutar la sentencia <b>$query</b>: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
    exit;
}

while($EstCta = $resultadoFC->fetch_array()) {
echo '
<tr>
<td>'.$EstCta['FechaDeFactura'] .'</td>
<td>'.$EstCta['id_facturadeventa'].'</td>
<td class="totalfactura">'.$EstCta['total'].'</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

';
}

while($EstCta = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
echo '
<tr>
<td>'.$EstCta['fechaCobro'].'</td>
<td>'.$EstCta['id_recibo'].'</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td class="importevalor">'.$EstCta['importe'].'</td>
</tr>

';
}


$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: las tablas en cuestión estan relacionadas por algun campo?

Comment: Si, se relacionan REC.id_cliente =  COM.id_cliente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya tienes dos tablas relacionadas, puedes incorporar la tabla de la 1ª consulta a esa relación, haciendo esto por ejemplo:

```
$query = "
SELECT 
    VAL.id_valrecibido, 
    VAL.id_recibo, 
    VAL.id_facturadeventa, 
    VAL.id_notadecredito, 
    VAL.tipovalor, 
    VAL.numerovalor, 
    VAL.banco, 
    VAL.provinciaIIBB, 
    VAL.cuentabancaria, 
    VAL.caja, 
    VAL.numretencion, 
    VAL.bancoprovincia, 
    VAL.bancoprovinciaValor, 
    VAL.vencimiento, 
    VAL.importe, 
    VAL.ActivoNoActivo, 
    REC.id_cliente, 
    REC.fechaCobro, 
    REC.fechaImputacion, 
    REC.recibo_numero, 
    CLI.razonsocial,
    COM.id_facturadeventa, 
    COM.id_cliente, 
    COM.FacturadorTalonario, 
    COM.TipoDeComprobante, 
    COM.FacturaLetra, 
    COM.facturaNumero, 
    COM.FechaDeFactura, 
    COM.total,COM.total, 
    COM.Anulada, 
    COM.Estado
FROM cobranzas_valrecibidos VAL 
    LEFT JOIN cobranzas_recibos REC ON VAL.id_recibo = REC.id_recibo
    LEFT JOIN clientes CLI          ON CLI.id_cliente = REC.id_cliente
    LEFT JOIN comprobantes COM      ON REC.id_cliente = COM.id_cliente
WHERE REC.id_cliente = '$cliente' 
ORDER BY REC.fechaCobro DESC, COM.FechaDeFactura DESC";
```

Nótese que no he incorporado a la consulta esto: `WHERE COM.id_cliente = '$cliente'`, porque `LEFT JOIN comprobantes COM ON REC.id_cliente = COM.id_cliente` ya filtrará en la tabla `COM` basándose en `WHERE REC.id_cliente = '$cliente'`.  En cuanto al `ORDER BY` he incorporado ambos, no sé cuál orden te interesa primero, en base a eso puedes poner primero una u otra columna.

---

> **NOTA SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD:**
>
> Tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Conviene
>   que te informes al respecto y que implementes consultas preparadas
>   para neutralizar ese riesgo.

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta muy acertada y útil. El problema que tengo aún es que no logro mostrar correctamente los datos. 
Con el siguiente _while_ muestra datos duplicados. 
`while($EstCta = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
echo '
<tr>
<td>'.$EstCta['FechaDeFactura'] .'</td>
<td>'.$EstCta['id_facturadeventa'].'</td>
<td class="totalfactura">'.$EstCta['total'].'</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

';

echo '
<tr>
<td>'.$EstCta['fechaCobro'].'</td>
<td>'.$EstCta['id_recibo'].'</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td class="importevalor">'.$EstCta['importe'].'</td>
</tr>

';
}
`